# Hibernate Criteria using collection (Set) in restrinction

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a Pojo class like below.

```
public class Book{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
  String name;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = false)
  Person owner;
}
```

I have Set of persons(owner) like Set owners. Now I want to fetch all the books of owners (Set). How can I add this condition in Hibernate criteria. I don't want to use HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `Restrictions.in` like so :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.in("owner", 
                               new Person[] {person1, person2, person1}));

List<Book> resultList = criteria.list();
```

Also I think it is possible to use :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.in("owner", 
                                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person1))));
```

Comment: Bro you took the words from my mouth, well pointed out in fact ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well with `Criteria` you can use **[`Restrictions.in()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection))** method like this:

```
List<Book> books = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
    .createAlias("owner", "o")
    .add(Restrictions.in("o", ownersCollection.toArray(new Book[ownersCollection.size()])))
    .list();
```

Where `ownersCollection`  is your collection of owners, in this code I used `ownersCollection` as a `List<Book>` but it will also work perfectly with `Set<Book>`.

Note that `.equals()` should be correctly implemented in your `Owner` class in order to get correct results.

For further reading about it you can check:

- [Hibernate **Criteria Queries** tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querycriteria.html).
- [How do I use Hibernate’s Restriction.in criterion?](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-use-hibernates-restriction-in-criterion/).